# What factors would cause a change in oscillation period as a result of a change in mass of pendulum bob?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, harmonic-oscillator, simulations, software

I'm running an experiment in a video-game simulator (ish) called 'G-MOD'. I setup a typical [pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)) setup, and measured the change in the period as a function of the pendulum's mass. I obviously expected the pendulum's period to remain a constant regardless of the change in mass. However, to my surprise, I noticed that as the mass increased there was a general positive increase of the period.

At first, I blamed air resistance; however from my knowledge air resistance shouldn't be impacted by the mass of an object, but only by its shape (aerodynamics), and since this is a video game I was able to make the shape of the pendulum bob identical while changing its mass.

I only possess a high-school level of understanding for physics, and I can't think of a reason as to why the mass would affect the period of a pendulum. Could anyone think of any answers to the pondering?

---

@Philip Here is the data pics
To clarify some things first, the masses were all in kg, the 'unit' listed is in game units; but through the developer's website I found some sort of conversion factor so I changed it to 'metres'.

This is the 'big range' of my independent variable. You can see I kinda gave up measuring for the unstableness reason I stated:
[image]

The second dataset is for the 'smaller range':
[image: jj]

Comment: may be the physics of the video game is not very accurate

Comment: or maybe it is *so* good that it it detecting the change in the moment of inertia of the mass. A pendulum NOT made of a point particle has a period dependent on the mass distribution. What shape is your pendulum and how are you changing its mass?

Comment: Is the density of the pendulum bob changing, or is its size growing? In the second case, it will add to the angular inertia, thus increasing the period.

Comment: Hi. This is an interesting question, but as such I don't think it can be answered well. Do you think you would be able to add some data to your question? I'd be very interested to see what it looks like. How are you measuring the period? Over how many oscillations are you averaging? What is the amount of change that you notice? What does the system look like (is it composite or "simple", as @JalfredP asks)? A lot of the time (even in real experiments) "increases" are inferred even when there are none, since the increase lies within range of uncertainties of the value itself.

Comment: Changing the mass without changing the size, shape, or aerodynamics does change the overall effect of the air resistance. Think of a feather, then the same feather made of lead..

Comment: @JalfredP It definitely isn't a point mass, it's a round sphere. Since it's not real-life, you're allowed to mess with an object's properties; in this case I just changed its numerical mass value by certain increments. What do you mean by mass distribution?

Comment: @dominecf The size is a constant; at least to my knowledge. I believe I'm just changing the density of the bob. Would the density affect the period?

Comment: @Philip I'll try to attach a picture of my results. Quick note, I tried the experiment twice; once with a small range of my independent variables (pendulum mass, I think I capped it at like 1600). Then the other trial was with a huge range, and looking at the data reminded me of an observation. The more I increased my mass, the more unstable and wobbly the pendulum became, it was a bit perplexing, but I thought I'd add it since that might be an indication of something.

Comment: @Philip Pt.2

I measured my period using a real-life stopwatch, I timed the amount of seconds needed for 10 oscillations, repeated it 3 times for each mass interval, then averaged it and divided it by 10.

The change in period is TINY, like a change of a few decimal points. And it's not proportional or anything too, just a positive correlation that slowly drops off. You may be right and I may be misreading it but I believe there definitely is an increase; especially when I compare the values of my maximum and minimum mass.

Comment: @AdrianHoward oof, yeah of course. That was a brain fart by me, so you think that applies to the pendulum setup here, and that could be a cause of the results?

Comment: @Maruwan Possibly, also if you are including the mass of the rod, then a heavier bob will lower the center of mass of the rod and bob.

Comment: The explanation might be hidden in how the software works or what settings were selected (perhaps by default). Does it take account of air resistance? Is the string elastic? (Increased mass will increase the length of the string which will increase period.) Does the string have mass? The spinning motion which you refer to in your notes could also affect the period.

Comment: did you do this in Gary's Mod? The Source engine doesn't follow true physics. We would have to know how the physics engine is coded to properly address your questions, but based on what I know about the Source engine, I wouldn't even expect things of different mass to fall at the same rate